# Copy and move images from one directory to another in xslt

Tags: xslt-2.0

I need to copy multiple images from one folder to another using xslt. 
Anyone can please help?

Comment: Are those images SVG images or another XML format? Or why do you want to use XSLT for the task of copying or moving files?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a good reason to do this job in XSLT, it can be done using the functions in the EXPath file module:

http://expath.org/spec/file

provided of course that there is an implementation available for your XSLT processor (there is in the case of Saxon).